# Change font spacing and size of bibunits \putbib

Tags: spacing, formatting, environments, fontsize, bibunits

In the following example I would like to force my references section to be typeset in a smaller font with single (more condensed) spacing.  My commands (a spacing environment call and a font small call) don't seem to pass the freshly requested parameters inside the `\putbib`. Note that my font size escape `\normalsize` is unnecessary as nothing changes even when this isn't present.

I presume this is similar to the popular question about changing font size in captions or figure legends, but since the solution to those generally involves option parameters I am hoping to come up with a generic way of overriding environment fonts or spacing so that this solution could also force changes in figure caption environments and my own clumsily defined environments (no example of a personal environment is provided because all I care about right now is bibunits).

```
\begin{filecontents}{mytestbib.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author = "Frank Mittelbach and Michel Goossens  and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle  and Chris Rowley",
    title = "The {LaTeX} Companion",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\singlespacing
\onehalfspacing
%\doublespacing
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[numbers,square,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{bibunits}
\defaultbibliography{mytestbib}
\defaultbibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}   %\nocite{*}       % list all refs in database, cited or not

\begin{document}

    \renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section*{\bibname}\markboth{\leftmark}{\bibname}}
    \begin{bibunit}
        \section{A section}
            There is text in a section, \lipsum and sometimes a reference is needed \cite{goossens93}

        \begin{singlespace}
        %   \small 
            \putbib 
        %   \normalsize 
            \end{singlespace}
    \end{bibunit}


    \doublespacing

    \begin{bibunit}
        \section{A second section}
        There is text in a section, \lipsum and sometimes a reference is needed \cite{goossens93}

        \begin{singlespace}
            %   \small 
            \putbib 
            %   \normalsize 
        \end{singlespace}
    \end{bibunit}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Spacing is single by default so switching to `singlespace` really isn't going to do anything much. Do you actually use a different setting for your main document?

Comment: @cfr Sorry reduced my example too much.  I indeed use a different spacing setting in my text.  I have updated my example, but I will have to update it again as the original `\begin{singlespace}` seems to work.  My document is far more complex with numerous formatting adjustments across parts etc. I will have to figure out which trigger here is creating a globally applied spacing parameter that can't be overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Since single-spacing is the default, there is nothing to do here unless your actual document uses another line spacing.
- `\renewcommand\bibfont{\small}` can be used to modify the font used for the bibliographies formatted using `natbib`.

I'm not sure what you have in mind when you mention a general solution which will work for captions and arbitrary environments as well. Generally, you need to manage each element on its own terms since each has its own syntax. Moreover, that syntax depends on the class and packages you are using. The `\bibfont` command is provided by `natbib`, for example, so this method will not work for arbitrary bibliographies in other documents unless you are also using `natbib` there.

Of course, you could create a package or class (or use one already in existence if applicable) so that a single option would set the font for a number of different elements of the document. You might want to look at the KOMA Script classes and packages, for example. But, regardless, that's something the code would need to do one way or another, and you'd still need to deal with differences between the syntax provided by different packages if different documents used different packages to customise similar document features.

[image: small bibliography]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Turns out there is no problem at all with latex defaults of single spacing, I had just never used it before to recognize it.  I was expecting significantly less white space.  Even your example picture seemed to show more than I was expecting.  I guess it must have been the significantly smaller font spacing I demoed in ms word that gave me the impression of extra compressed spacing.  I assume theres no more compact spacing than single?

Comment: @EngBIRD Well, you can even make the spacing negative if you like. But there is no out-of-the-box setting more compact than single as far as I know. But do you really want the lines typeset closer than that, especially when you are already using a small size? (Do you have no pity for your readers?)

Comment: Because `LaTeX` makes it so easy to generate multiple copies of the document for different purposes, the decreased line spacing was to save paper on printing this massive document.  Because I use `bibunits` I get repeated references throughout hundreds of pages and to save a bit of paper I was going to compress it as much as possible.  While I don't think I will go so far as to use negative spacing, I think I will look into it for interests sake.  Thanks for your comments, and your answer resizing the `bibfont`.  I had see this before but thought it would be different when using `bibunits`.

Comment: @EngBIRD I'd use a smaller font or fontsize rather than reduce the line spacing. `\footnotesize` or a different font. But if you change the font, don't just do it for the references, obviously.